# Объединение Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

Как объединить две или более bitmap с прозрачностью в одну, в C#?

Comment: Что конкретно вы понимаете под *"объединить"*?

Comment: @Dmitry D. , Всм есть у нас первый битмап с каким-либо узором, и второй с какой-либо фигурой, а фон на неё был прозрачный. И всё это надо объединить один битмап, на котором был узор и поверх него фигура

Comment: ну и рисуйте один поверх другого. Прозрачность именно для этого и нужна, чтобы не думать, а просто накладывать слои один на другой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

используйте CompositingMode.SourceOver

```
Bitmap baseImage;
Bitmap overlayImage;

baseImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\150\base.png");
overlayImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\150\tb.png");

var finalImage = new Bitmap(overlayImage.Width, overlayImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(finalImage);
graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;

graphics.DrawImage(baseImage, 0, 0);
graphics.DrawImage(overlayImage, 0, 0);

//Отображаем изображение на форме
pictureBox1.Image = finalImage;
```

**Результат:**

[image]